# how to connect the database while using qt

Tags: sqlite

C:\Users\PC\Documents\KAFUE-TOURIST-MANAGEMENT\addpackage.h:3: error: databaseheader.h: No such file or directory
In file included from C:/Users/PC/Documents/KAFUE-TOURIST-MANAGEMENT/addpackage.cpp:1:
C:/Users/PC/Documents/KAFUE-TOURIST-MANAGEMENT/addpackage.h:3:10: fatal error: databaseheader.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include <databaseheader.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

qDebug()<<"PackageName"<<PackageName<<"PackageDescription"<<PackageDescription<<"Amount"<<Amount;

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.set
```

i was expecting it to show me that the database has be found